# Authenticate with a Laravel-Passport Oauth 2.0 back-end via spoofing a Bearer token?

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to authentcate with my API without the frontend of my environment so I can test my API end points with postman or some sort of client. I have a Baerer token I took from my frontend axios requests but apparently Laravel wont take it and just returns `Route login not defined` IE meaning its trying to redirect to the login so it can't auth.

So I tried generating a new one with Insomnia, similar to postman since postman gave me the `Route not defined` issue so I gave up wih it.

Going to: http://api-core.test/api/oauth/token

Passing:

```
client_id=2
client_secret=...
grant_type=client_credentials
username=...@example.com
password=...
scope=
```

And now its just spitting out

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
  "hint": "Check that all required parameters have been provided"
}
```

Comment: For postman to work the request needs to expect json. If `expectsJson` from the `request` returns false, you'll get a redirect on the unauthenticated response. Send an `Accept` header with the value of `application/json`

Comment: Tried this, It returns `{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}`

Comment: Your credentials are wrong. Looks like you are sending a username/password. The grant_type should be `password`.